# Using a class for an ArrayList inside of a switch statement

Tags: java, string, class, arraylist, switch-statement

I'm trying to use a class to represent the data that is inputted into an array list. The data inputted contains a string, E30, another string, 1985, then a variable contained in the swithc statement, ratingE30.

I can't get the class to work with the arraylist. If I leave the strings without quotation marks I get a cannot resolve symbol error yet with them it doesnt work either as it says the string is not compatible with my class Data.

Any help would be appreciated.

ArrayList located in public static void main(String[] args ):

```
ArrayList<Data> arrayListToFile = new ArrayList<Data>();
arrayListToFile.add(new Data[]{"E30",1985,ratingE30});
```

Data class for the ArrayList located in Main:

```
private static class Data{
    String Model;
    String ModelYear;

    Data(String Model,String ModelYear){
        this.Model=Model;
        this.ModelYear=ModelYear;

    }
}
```

Comment: You are creating an `ArrayList<Data>` and you are trying to pass to sth that would be an `ArrayList<Data[]>`

Answer (score 0):

I think you want

```
arrayListToFile.add(new Data("E30",1985,ratingE30));
```

Although that will only work if you add an appropriate constructor to your `Data` class.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you said that you are trying to use the class to represent the data, It has two fields, where is the rating field(or what do you want to do with ratingE30?)?
Maybe what you want is something like this

```
private static class Data{
    String model; 
    String modelYear;
    String rating; // I declared it as String because i have no idea what it contains

    Data(String model, String modelYear, String rating){
        this.model = model;
        this.modelYear = modelYear;
        this.rating = rating;

    }
}
```

Secondly if you want to have a List of Data objects you should add Data objects to your list! 
For example (using the extended class from above):

```
ArrayList<Data> arrayListToFile = new ArrayList<Data>();
arrayListToFile.add(new Data("E30", "1985", ratingE30);
```

Looking at your code I am not sure what did you want with the Data[] array, but the way you initialized it was wrong as well, Data[] array just like the ArrayList requies Data objects but what you passed were just a String, an int and i am not sure about the last.

```
new Data[] {new Data("E30", "1985", ratingE30)};
```

If you are not sure how [objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html)/[arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) work read more about them